# Sharing Website URL and Content with Facebook

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, facebook, facebook-sharer

I want to share URL & Text with Facebook.right now sharing link is OK but how to add Text or content? I have using below mention code for facebook sharing.

```
<div>
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
   <script>    (function (d, s, id) {
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(ienter code hered)) return;
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=*********";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
   </script>
   </div>

   <div class="fb-share-button"  
         data-href="http://localhost:1493/FBShare.aspx"  
         data-type="button_count"></div>
```

Comment: Did you check the Facebook documentation? I think what you are looking for is the [FB.ui()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui) method.

Comment: Whats the url of the page you want to share?